# Update de valor de um índice de um array de um documento MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Galera, gostaria de saber como atualizar um valor de um documento que está dentro de um array. Veja o documento:

```
> db.alunos.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ba141b186b9fc17121423a1"),
        "nome" : "Diego",
        "cursos" : [
                {
                        "nome" : "Design Responsivo com Twitter Bootstrap",
                        "cargaHoraria" : 80
                },
                {
                        "nome" : "NodeJS",
                        "cargaHoraria" : 100
                }
        ]
}
```

Eu preciso atualizar a cargaHoraria do curso com nome NodeJS. No caso está com a carga horária de 100h. Gostaria de atualizar somente esse curso para a carga horária de 120h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [$operador condicional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) junto com o [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) do mongodb

```
db.alunos.update(
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5ba141b186b9fc17121423a1"),
      "cursos.nome": "NodeJS"
      }, 
    { "$set": { "cursos.$.cargaHoraria": 120 } }
)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Viniiciius! Deu certo.